# Simple AngularJS drag & drop solution

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

There are solutions that require hundreds of libraries to be included and it's obviously not satisfactory. I know there are quite a few questions about drag & drop, but my requirements are different and much less demanding than previous questions. All I need is to be able to drag & drop items, and somehow get references to both of those items, so I could do the swapping (changing values between the items) myself. So I guess, that would require smaller library, or maybe a simpler solution..?

```
<ul>
    <li sortable ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}} <i id="draggableIcon"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)? I'm not sure if it fits your needs, but it supports moving elements between different lists

Comment: @Jason It requires JQueryUI to be included

Comment: It's dead easy to add ondragstart and and on ondrop events to pass your values. Why not just code them in?

Comment: @good_evening That's true, but it's only one extra library, and you can create a lean build of jQueryUI to get only the elements you need

Comment: OK. but all you need is two three line functions to pass your data from the drag source to the drop source. Your call ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
// just some old fashioned java-script to drop data from one element to another!

sourceElement.ondragstart = function(ev) {

      var datastr = "" // pass an object id, or an object as json what ever you need
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", datastr);
}
// Allow drops to your target
targetElement.ondragover = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
}

targetElement.ondrop = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      datastr = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
      // do something cool here with that data!
}
```

Comment: You can also just bind these functions in your html or a template.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ui and Angular-dragdrop:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-dragdrop.min.js" type='text/javascript"></script>
```

Download the angular-dragdrop.min.js file @
https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js

Draggable:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" ng-hide="!list1.title">{{list1.title}}</div>
```

Droppable:

```
<div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-droppable style='height:50px;'><div class="btn btn-success" data-drag="false" data-jqyoui-options ng-model="list2" jqyoui-draggable ng-hide="!list2.title">{{list2.title}}</div>
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
var App = angular.module('drag-and-drop', ['ngDragDrop']);
App.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list1 = {title: 'AngularJS - Drag Me'};
  $scope.list2 = {};

  $scope.startCallback = function(event, ui, title) {
    console.log('You started draggin: ' + title.title);
    $scope.draggedTitle = title.title;
  };

  $scope.stopCallback = function(event, ui) {
    console.log('Why did you stop draggin me?');
  };

  $scope.dragCallback = function(event, ui) {
    console.log('hey, look I`m flying');
  };

  $scope.dropCallback = function(event, ui) {
    console.log('hey, you dumped me :-(' , $scope.draggedTitle);
  };
});
```

Demo: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/

Angular-dragdrop: https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to a simple solution, with no JQuery/JQueryUI dependency.

After testing a bunch of libraries, I found [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/angular-dragdrop/angular-dragdrop) interesting. At least, it fits my needs, is very easy to configure and has a very small package size (~6K).

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row topRow">
        <h4 class="heading">
            Drag and drop between the two lists.
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <ul ui-on-Drop="onDrop($event,$data,men)">
                <li ui-draggable="true" drag="man" 
                on-drop-success="dropSuccessHandler($event,$index,men)"
                ng-repeat="man in men track by $index">
                    {{man}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <ul ui-on-Drop="onDrop($event,$data,women)">
                <li ui-draggable="true" drag="woman" 
                on-drop-success="dropSuccessHandler($event,$index,women)"
                ng-repeat="woman in women track by $index">
                    {{woman}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only cons is the poor documentation. But, even with that, it is easy to put it running.